# De/Serialzing custom java types with protobuf in java

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

protocul buffer supports only a close set of types, like int32, strings, repeted, etc.

The problem is that I want to create a custom deserializer for specific things. For example, look at this proto message:

```java
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message UberDrive {
  string user_id = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp transaction_timestamp = 2;
  string start_locaion = 3; //WKT data
  string end_locaion = 3; //WKT data
}
```

Currently, the start_location and end_location just contain WKT data that, later, when needed in the code, is serialized to an `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry.class` object (which can be a point, linestring, polygon, etc.).

I would like to work directly with the Geometry data type in my pojo to avoid serializing the geometry over and over again and for cleaner code. Is there a way to do that?

I couldn't find any solution for what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a way to do that.

Comment: Pardon me, but I would like to know why a user of your stature chose to post an answer which, in my opinion, should clearly be posted as a comment.

Comment: No, I'm actually going to push back against that.  The question in the OP was "is there a way to do that?"  The answer is no, there is not.  Protobuf does not expose a way to include POJOs or any objects other than those created by protobuf (and proto-supported scalars) in the hierarchy of a proto type.  This directly, and accurately, answers the OP's question; I stand by it.